# How do I enable an onclick event in a link on a form?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I am using the following code.

```
 $form['test'] = array(
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#href' => "javascript:;",
        '#title' => t('Show'),
        '#attributes' => array(
            'onclick' => "show_this();",
            'onsubmit' => 'return false',
        ),
        '#id' => 'myid',
  );
```

Its output is the following.

```
<a href="/javascript%3A%3B" onclick="show_this();" onsubmit="return false" id="myid">Show</a>
```

The *onclick* event is working properly. I want to disable href.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `#href` to prevent the event.

```
$form['test'] = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#href' => '#',
  '#title' => t('Show'),
  '#attributes' => [
    'onclick' => "alert('hello');return false",
  ],
  '#id' => 'myid',
];
```

In the above example, I removed the `#href` and the `onsubmit` handler and added `return false` after the `alert()` function in the `onclick` handler.
I don't know what  you're trying to achieve in your code, but the above example is working for me.

---

UPDATE:
I update the `#href` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @ismail-cherri, but i got error : `Notice: Undefined index: #href in drupal_pre_render_link()`

Comment: I updated the answer to include a # for href